# Merge cells in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working on generating excel report using vba code. I am new in this. Just wanted to know if i need to merge any particular range of columns/cells but not sure from where they start but always ends up after 5 cells.

Below is my code:

```
ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 1).Value = RS("Fund")
```

from above line, value is being set in 7th row and let say col value is 6 then above line will set the value in 7th row 7th column. But what i need that it should merge cells from 7th to 12th along with its text.

Please help me solving this.

Comment: Do you need to physically merge the five cells so after that merge instead of five cell you have one big cell? Or you just need to write one common value to those five cells at once? You do not need to physically merge cells to write a common value to them. IMHO merged cells are evil thing :-).

Comment: merging cells is the devil's work - there is always a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

this will merge 5 cells horizontally. You can change 7 to the row number and add 5 in the second part like I have added 6 below to merge vertically

**Col + 6** = Ensures that **5 Cells to the Right of Col + 1 are merged together**

```
Range(Cells(7, Col + 1), Cells(7, Col + 6)).Merge
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multicell range by referencing two cells in the same worksheet.

```
range(ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 1), ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 6))
```

To merge then just call .merge

```
range(ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 1), ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 6)).merge
```

If you want to get fancy and do more formatting with the same range then you can use a with block and keep it looking neater.

```
with range(ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 1), ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 6))
    .merge
    .HorizontalAlignment= xlCenter
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Resize()` method to extend the range you are currently utilizing to a set amount of rows/columns like so:

```
ShtReport.Cells(7, col + 1).Resize(1, 6).Value = RS("Fund")
'// Resize(1, 6) = Resize to 1 row and 6 columns
```

---